# Reading a file line by line with strings and integers

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to read the information from the following file:

```
The Firm
Dell
512
Fundamentals of Computer Graphics
A K Peters, Ltd.
662
The C++ Programming Language
Addison-Wesley Professional
911
Northwest Airlines
Plymouth Toy & Book
96
Lonely Planet: Europe on a Shoestring
Lonely Planet Publications
1324
…
```

The file lists books with the first line being the Title, second line is Publisher, and third line is Number of pages.It repeats for five books. I'm trying to read the information and store them into the vector in the Library class.

```
class book

{


public:

    book();


    book(string t, string p, int num);


    string getTitle();
    string getPublisher();
    int getPageNum();


    void setTitle(string t);
    void setPublisher(string p);
    void setPageNum(int num);


    string title;
    string publisher;
    int num_of_pages;

};



  class library
    {
    public:
        vector<book> collection;

        bool contains(string title);

        void addBook(book b);

        void readFile(string fileName);
    }
```

Here is the readFile function:

```
   void library::readFile(string fileName)
    {
        ifstream infile;
        infile.open(fileName.c_str());
        if (infile.fail())
        {
            cout<<"Error opening file."<<endl<<endl;
            exit(1);
        }

       book addition;
string line;

while (!infile.eof())
{
    getline(infile, addition.title);
    getline(infile, addition.publisher);
    getline(infile, line);
    addition.num_of_pages=atoi(line.c_str());
    collection.push_back(addition);  
}


        collection.push_back(addition);


    }
```

One final issue: The output is not working properly. Everything in the file is listed under the title.

```
ostream &operator <<(ostream& out, const book& b1)
{
    out<<"TITLE: "<<b1.title<<endl;
    out<<"PUBLISHER: "<<b1.publisher<<endl;
    out<<"NUMBER OF PAGES: "<<b1.num_of_pages<<endl;

    return out;
}
```

Main code:

```
int i;
                for (i=0; i<book_library.collection.size(); i++)
                {
                    cout<<book_library.collection[i]<<endl;
                }
```

Output:

```
TITLE: The Firm
Dell
512
Fundamentals of Computer Graphics
A K Peters, Ltd.
662
The C++ Programming Language
Addison-Wesley Professional
911
Northwest Airlines
Plymouth Toy & Book
96
Lonely Planet: Europe on a Shoestring
Lonely Planet Publications
1324
\311
PUBLISHER: 
NUMBER OF PAGES: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

One simplification could be, since `getline` returns an `istream`, to test it directly in the `while` condition:

```
while (getline(infile, addition.title)) {
    getline(infile, addition.publisher);
    getline(infile, line);
    addition.num_of_pages = atoi(line.c_str()); // string -> int
    collection.push_back(addition);  // you should push_back in the while loop
}
```

Comment: Its throwing me an error with the atoi function. Xcode says there is no matching function. Is line the right parameter?

Comment: @iamthewalrus I've updated it to `line.c_str()`, please refresh the page.

Comment: @iamthewalrus Could you accept the answer if you find it helpful? Thanks!

Comment: Please check my last question in the newly edited code if you have time!

Comment: Could you try debugging the code? Put a `cout << addition` in the end of the while to check if each book is read properly.

Comment: Yes, I did that and it gave me the same result as in the output above, hence the books are not being read properly?

Comment: I mean, at the end of the while loop, you out put `addition.title`, `addition.publiser`, etc. Are these values correct?

Comment: They are not, the entire file is being stored in b1.title.

Comment: @iamthewalrus Could you post your code and data file somewhere? The getline is supposed to read line by line, and it's hard to tell where it goes wrong.

Comment: @iamthewalrus It works fine on my computer. I think there are some problems with the newlines. Maybe the text file is created in Linux and you're using Windows. You can try paste and save it into another text file and read it again.

Answer (score 0):

You could define an extraction operator for your `book` class to keep things encapsulated, as well as using the standard built-in extraction operators (>>) to save yourself temp variables and conversions:

```
std::ifstream & operator>>(std::ifstream & str, book & b)
{
    str >> b.title >> b.publisher >> b.num_of_pages;
    return str;
}

std::ifstream infile;
book addition;
std::vector<book> collection;
while ( infile >> addition)
{
    collection.push_back(addition);
}
```

Comment: You can't do this. There are spaces in the titles and publishers.